# Returning Neo4j server plugin results as graphML?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-java-api

Is there a way to return the path from my server plugin in a graphML format? Like the way it can be done in the usual REST endpoint by providing resultDataContents as "graph".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just create the graphml format and return it as a string. For an example on how to do it:

https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-shell-tools/blob/2.2/src/main/java/org/neo4j/shell/tools/imp/format/XmlGraphMLFormat.java

Comment: Thanks. I assume it should be done using server extensions instead of plugins.